# JSON Structure changed, breaks methods

Tags: php, php-7

Currently, I have below JSON stored in my database:

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "row": "My name is Trevor"
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "row": "Hey there! Some other text."
        }
    ],
    "3": [
        {
            "row": "And more."
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, the third party API that I am using have changed their output format to:

```
[
   {
      "0":"My name is Trevor"
   },
   {
      "0":"Hey there! Some other text."
   },
   {
      "0":"And more."
   }
]
```

I have a PHP function that reads the array-like colums and transforms each column/row. I can call it like:

```php
public function apply(array $table) : array
{
    return $this->applyRule($table);
}
```

Which calls this:

```php
public function applyRule(array $table): array
{
    $out = [];
    foreach ($table as $col => $rows) {
            $out[$col] = array_map([$this, 'rule'], $rows);
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Which ultimately calls the parsing rule, like so:

```php
public function rule($content) : array
{
    return preg_replace($this->pattern, $this->replacement, $content);
}
```

However, running above gives me below error:

```
regexTextReplace::rule() must be of the type array, string returned
```

I suspect that due to the change in the JSON structure, my parsing functions no longer work.

I am not sure what needs to be changed - can someone assist me?

## Edit:

So looking at the answer below, adding `[$rows]` instead of `$rows` fixes the error, but ultimately creates a nested array it seems.

If I do a die-dump like:

```php
dd($rows);
```

It actually does return an array:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "My name is Trevor"
  1 => ""
  2 => ""
]
```

So why is it seen as a string?

Comment: What's in `$rows`? If you change to `array_map([$this, 'rule'], [$rows]);`, it works?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte That... Works? Just be adding `[]` around `$rows`. How come?

Comment: Because in the previous response, it was returning an array but now it is returning an object. So it simply wraps the object with an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send `$rows` as an array to the `rule()` function, just wrapping it in `[]`:

```
array_map([$this, 'rule'], [$rows]);
```

Then the function will receive an array, not a string.

Otherwise, you can refactor your code and use a string instead, but I can't see much advantage.

Comment: I tried adding `[$rows]`- but this turns it into a nested array it seems. I have updated my question, and added the dump of `$rows`, as you can see - it is already an array?